# Serial Monitor stops working when using PinMode

Tags: arduino-uno, serial

I'm having a lot of trouble with my recent Arduino sketch. I need to reset an IC by setting a pin high then low. I also am using the serial monitor for some testing but as soon as I try and do a Serial.print, nothing appears. My Arduino is also on a custom PCB, where D7 is connected to the IC's (MAX3421) reset pin, and also to the Arduino's reset pin.
To try and make my issue clearer, ill post some code and the serial monitor output below:

```
void setup() 
{
  Serial.begin(9600); 
  
  pinMode(7, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() 
{
  Serial.println("TEST");
}
```

[nothing in serial monitor]

---

```
void setup() 
{
  Serial.begin(9600); 
  
  //pinMode(7, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() 
{
  Serial.println("TEST");
}
```

[lots of TESTs]

Any help is appreciated,
Thomas

Comment: You are probably shorting or browning out something.  What exactly do you have attached to pin 7?

Comment: I'm using one of my custom PCBs with an Arduino and a MAX3421 for interfacing with USB peripherals. 
Pin 7 is connected to MAX3421's reset pin which now I look, is also connected to the Arduino reset pin. I remember doing this because it was necessary to reset the MAX before starting. Is shorting the MAXs reset with the Arduino's reset doing this?

Comment: put another serial.print() in setup() ... that way you can tell if the arduino is resetting

Comment: I put a `Serial.println("x");` before the `pinMode` and it didn't print anything which is puzzling

Comment: "Is shorting the MAXs reset with the Arduino's reset doing this?" In a word, yes.

Comment: @VosemMedia You would also need to insert a short delay after the print. The data is send out via interrupts after the print call. So you are resetting the Arduino before the UART interface has enough time to send the data out

Comment: Ah yes, I added a short delay and now only the x is being printed over and over. I am now wondering why my code doesn't work as shorting MAX Reset and Arduino Reset should work though i'm still getting the same `OSC did not start.` error.

Comment: Okay that's extremely weird, for some reason it just started working, then I unplugged everything and plugged in again and it no longer works.

Comment: This may seem kind of obtuse, but do you understand what RESET pin does on the UNO?

Comment: My understanding is that it re-executes the current program though that may be incorrect, just from my experience that's what it seems to do

Comment: Also, I fixed my main issue which was the MAX not getting enough power from the USB header, so I introduced a 9v battery which sorted it all. I would love to understand the reset pin more but if you don't think it's in the scope of this question don't worry :)

Comment: This normally not meant for discussion, so this is going to be a one-shot comment to address that:  When reset is active (low), the 328P is electrically disconnected from circuit and execution is halted.  When it comes out of RESET is essentially rebooted, like a computer. Owing to what the chip itself does and what the start code does, you've functionally (oversimplifying) lost all prior state.  If you really want to know about it, you want to read in the [ATMega328P](https://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/ATMEGA328P) datasheet.

Comment: I appreciate the explanation, thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My issue was that pin 7 was connected to the reset pin on the Arduino, meaning every time it was set to output, the Arduino was reset.
You can see this here:

```
void setup() 
{
  Serial.begin(9600); 

  Serial.println("a");

  delay(100);
    
  pinMode(7, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() 
{
  Serial.println("test");
}
```

which outputs a stream of a's separated by 100ms (plus a bit)

Comment: I added more information to the question, and don't doubt others have had the same problem so I will keep the question/solution up.